# how to call a function inside another function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to call a function inside another function in javascript, actually trying to call `populateCurrencies()` inside `startApp()`. What am I doing wrong?

```
const startApp = () => {
   const populateCurrencies = (); 

function populateCurrencies() {

    alert(return this.option.value + " " + this.option.textContent);
}

const startApp = () {};
```

Comment: You’re missing a close `}` somewhere in there

Comment: You have a bunch of basic syntax errors. What is `populateCurrencies = ();` supposed to be? And it's the same name as the function you define on the next line.

Comment: What is `const startApp = () {};` supposed to do?

Comment: Is it supposed to be `const startApp = () => { some code in here };`

Comment: @Barmar ok, its a currency app assignment, am supposed to call the populateCurrencies function inside the already declared startApp function

Comment: Something like that `function startup(){function popularcurrency(); }`

Answer (score 1):

You are using a invalid syntax.

You declare functions like this (with arrow function expression).

```
const myFunc = () => {
 // Code to run here...
}
```

And you call your function like this.

```
myFunc();
```

Not `const myFunc = () {};` like it is in your example.

Also, const is a constant, you can't have multiple constants with the same name, so that's an error as well. And if you want to reassign values to a variable you have to use `let` instead. But that's beside the point since you won't need those extra variable declarations that you have now when you call the functions.